# How do I iterate over a SPARQL query referring to a virtual graph?

Tags: stored-procedures, iteration, sparql, virtuoso, r2rml

I am developing a Virtuoso stored procedure. 
I want to perform a loop over the result of a SPARQL query to a graph. 
The problem comes when the query contains a reference to a virtual graph (a graph not physically in the triplestore, being the result of a R2RML mapping operation). In all my attempts I get no error but an empty resultset as well. 
I tried the following

```
create procedure R2RML.DBA.try() returns integer
{
  for (sparql define input:storage ""
       select ?s ?p
       from <http://example.com/resource>
       where {
         ?s <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> ?o .
       }  LIMIT 5 ) do
    {
      use_the_value("s");
    }
};
```

and also the following

```
create procedure R2RML.DBA.try() returns integer
{
  declare srcgraph varchar;
  srcgraph := 'http://ec.example.com/resource';
  for (sparql define input:storage ""
        select ?s ?p
        where {
        GRAPH `iri(?:srcgraph)` 
          {
            ?s <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> ?o .
          }
        }  LIMIT 5 ) do
    {
      use_the_value("s");
    }
};
```

In both cases no iteration is performed, despite the same query, when executed in the SPARQL endpoint, returns a result.

If I remove the reference to the graph the iterations are executed:

```
create procedure R2RML.DBA.try() returns integer
{
  for (sparql define input:storage ""
        select ?s ?p
        where {
          ?s <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> ?o .
        }  LIMIT 5 ) do
    {
      use_the_value("s");
    }
};
```

Has somebody any idea of what I get wrong?

Comment: This looks more like an appropriate question for the Virtuoso mailing list as this is pretty a specific question. But probably @TallTed will answer your question here.

Answer (score 0):

Since the graph is virtual, the trick is to add the name of the quad storage in the `define` directive in the SPARQL statement. For example if the Virtuoso quad map storage is used the `define` directive will become the following.

```
sparql define input:storage "http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#DefaultQuadStorage"
```